# How can I download only certain columns of a compressed (bgz) file using wget?

Tags: wget, download

We need to download a 182 GB compressed file (uncompressed as a [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values)). However, we only need the first five columns of the file, which equates to approximately 1 GB.

Is there some fancy shell magic that can be done to download a subset of a file?

Downloading the whole file only to delete 99% of it really kills our server's storage.

**What is being downloaded:** [gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz](https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz) from [gnomad.broadinstitute.org](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/downloads).

Any alternatives solutions are welcome. I'm interested in solutions that work for non-compressed files as well.

The gist is, how do I avoid downloading a massive file when I only need a subset of that file?

Comment: It would be good to know exactly how much of the file should be downloaded in advance. You could spawn a process that would watch a size of the partially downloaded file (in a busy loop though, I don't know any other method to do that, inotify will not be very useful) and kill wget process when the size is reached.

Comment: .bgz is a compressed file, so to extract content it needs to be uncompressed first. I doubt any solutions exist that would uncompress a compressed file at the source to download only part of it.

Comment: It may (although I doubt it since you don't want certain lines but instead certain parts of every line) be relevant to note that this is bgzipped and not gzipped, and bgzip is an indexed compression format.

Comment: http://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html is a copy of the man page, in case anyone's interested.  It's a blocked GZIP, with 64KiB blocks by default.

Comment: For the curious: this exact problem is why *column store* database formats exist, where every column is a separate file.

Answer (score 31):

You can download the file, filter it, and then write the result to your local disk

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz |
    bgzip -d |
    cut -f1-5
```

This still requires you to download the full file but only the filtered amount gets written to disk.

On Debian the `bgzip` command is provided by the `tabix` package. But if that's not installed you can also use `gzip`'s `zcat` to read `bgzip`-compressed files (`curl … | zcat | cut -f1-5`).

---

I've had some queries about the amount of data storage this pipeline will require. Here is a real run. Notice that on this system I've only got 2GB of available storage in total; nowhere near the 182GB required to download and save the file even compressed:

```
# How much disk space available in my current directory?
df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.9G  5.6G  2.0G  75% /

# Download and filter the file, saving only the result
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz |
bgzip -d |
cut -f1-5 > bigfile

# What did we get, and how much disk space remains?
ls -lh bigfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 1.7G Feb  7 05:09 bigfile

df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.9G  7.2G  347M  96% /
```

Interestingly, I note that the file is *not strictly* TSV (tab-separated values) format. Of its 59,160,934 lines, 942 do not contain tab separated data.

```
file bigfile
bigfile: Variant Call Format (VCF) version 4.2, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Comment: "...only the filtered amount gets written to disk" Are you sure? I know people in 2040 will look back and laugh at this comment, but currently not many computers have 182GB of RAM in which to hold the file before writing to disk.

Comment: @GlenYates yes I'm sure. What are you seeing that I'm not? We download the data to a pipe that cuts out the first five tab-separated columns per requirements. If the OP didn't have space to store that then nothing anyone can offer will help

Comment: @roaima: Glen seems to think that either `bgzip` or `cut` will not produce output until the input is complete, which would require 182GB of RAM. If both can stream input, then you're right that the whole file doesn't need to be held.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't understand why GlenYates (or you?) think this is even an issue. It's a command pipeline. No temporary files. That's why I've written "_only the filtered amount gets written to disk_"

Comment: @roaima: Command pipelines stream data from one command/process to another. if one of those processes, such as `cut` first reads the entire input into memory before it emits anything, then that process will take 182GB of memory. I do not know enough linux to know if `bgzip` or `cut` or `zcat` require the whole file to first be read into memory internally.  `sort`, for instance, definitely reads the whole input into memory. `uniq` as well.  I assume you're correct that `bgzip` and `cut` do not require that, but I don't actually know for certain.

Comment: @MooingDuck ok, I think I understand your concern. You don't need to worry - `sort` does have to read its entire input (unless you're doing a merge sort, that is). `uniq` does not need to read its entire input before writing anything. `bgzip`, `zcat`, and `cut` - along with most other filter utilities - also do not. I'm currently running a demonstrable proof on a filesystem with only 2GB available space. So far I've downloaded 5.5GB and written just 51MB

Comment: @MooingDuck Just an addendum to roaima's comment, `uniq` specifically requires its input to be pre-sorted to get a valid "fully unique" result because it compares adjacent lines instead of reading the whole input to compare across everything.

Comment: @GlenYates: `.bgz` is a streaming compression format, actually using a pretty small max block size (only 64KiB), so that's the most a decompresser would need to look ahead in the compressed input before it could write output to a pipe.  (Actually that's a very conservative upper bound).  Other compression schemes like LZMA can use quite large compression dictionaries, like 1GiB if you tell the compressor to do so, and that's the sort of thing that will boost the memory requirement for a decompressor.  But still not for buffering of I/O streams, rather for the (de)compression dictionary.

Comment: @MooingDuck, incidentally, _no_ `sort` doesn't "definitely" read data into memory: When BSD sort is given a file larger than (by default) 90% of available RAM, it partitions it out into distinct temporary files on disk, sorts those individually, and then does a merge sort to combine them back to a single stream. You're right that it does need to store the content _somewhere_, but wrong to assert that the somewhere in question is definitely in RAM. (GNU sort has similar capabilities, but the 90% figure is from BSD docs)

Answer (score 18):

Simply no, there isn't.

I have looked at the data and as you said the file is quite big, so I didn't quite download it.

Second thing you say file is TSV:

> ... we only need the first 5 columns of the binary TSV formatted file ...

If I interpret your abbreviation correctly, you mean `TSV` as in `Tab Separated Value` file, in which case it is regular text file and not a binary file. Of course from certain point of view even text files are binary files - but in this case we are talking about text file.

However the file is indeed compressed:

```
: curl -s -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | file -
/dev/stdin: Blocked GNU Zip Format (BGZF; gzip compatible), block length 4462
```

As somebody already answered, this means, you can use streaming technique to unpack file on the fly, by sending it over pipe to decompresor. `bgzcat` doesn't seem to exist in my distro, but `zcat`, which is quite universal, is in my distro and knows how to read this compressed stream:

```
: curl -s -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | zcat | head -n 1              
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
```

Investigating further, beginning of the file there are comments:

```
curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | zcat | head -n 80
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##hailversion=0.2.77-684f32d73643
##FILTER=<ID=AC0,Description="Allele count is zero after filtering out low-confidence genotypes (GQ < 20; DP < 10; and AB < 0.2 for het calls)">
##FILTER=<ID=AS_VQSR,Description="Failed VQSR filtering thresholds of -2.7739 for SNPs and -1.0606 for indels">
##FILTER=<ID=InbreedingCoeff,Description="InbreedingCoeff < -0.3">
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="Passed all variant filters">
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Alternate allele count">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Alternate allele frequency">
##INFO=<ID=popmax,Number=A,Type=String,Description="Population with maximum allele frequency">
##INFO=<ID=faf95_popmax,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Filtering allele frequency (using Poisson 95% CI) for the population with the maximum allele frequency">
##INFO=<ID=AC_non_v2_XX,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Alternate allele count for XX samples in non_v2 subset">
##INFO=<ID=AN_non_v2_XX,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in XX samples in non_v2 subset">
##INFO=<ID=AF_non_v2_XX,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Alternate allele frequency in XX samples in non_v2 subset">
##INFO=<ID=nhomalt_non_v2_XX,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Count of homozygous individuals in XX samples in non_v2 subset">
##INFO=<ID=AC_non_cancer_fin_XX,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Alternate allele count for XX samples of Finnish ancestry in non_cancer subset">
##INFO=<ID=AN_non_cancer_fin_XX,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in XX samples of Finnish ancestry in non_cancer subset">
##INFO=<ID=AF_non_cancer_fin_XX,Number=A,Type=Float,Description="Alternate allele frequency in XX samples of Finnish ancestry in non_cancer subset">
```

Finally @943 line probably headers start:

```
: curl -s -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | zcat | tail -n+943 | head -n 1 
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
```

I am too lazy to determine which is actually column delimiter in the first data line, but it seems "\t" is indeed column separator:

```
: curl -s -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | zcat | tail -n+944 | head -n 1 
chr1    10031   .   T   C   .   AC0;AS_VQSR AC=0;AN=56642;AF=0.00000;AC_non_v2_XX=0;AN_non_v2_XX=23674;AF_non_v2_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_v2_XX=0;AC_non_cancer_fin_XX=0;AN_non_cancer_fin_XX=1060;AF_non_cancer_fin_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_cancer_fin_XX=0;AC_non_neuro_nfe=0;AN_non_neuro_nfe=24462;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.00000;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=0;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=0;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=5226;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=0;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=9974;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=392;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0;AC_non_neuro_sas_XX=0;AN_non_neuro_sas_XX=260;AF_non_neuro_sas_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_neuro_sas_XX=0;AC_non_v2=0;AN_non_v2=44696;AF_non_v2=0.00000;nhomalt_non_v2=0;AC_non_topmed_nfe_XX=0;AN_non_topmed_nfe_XX=2800;AF_non_topmed_nfe_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_topmed_nfe_XX=0;AC_non_v2_mid=0;AN_non_v2_mid=192;AF_non_v2_mid=0.00000;nhomalt_non_v2_mid=0;AC_non_topmed_sas=0;AN_non_topmed_sas=1114;AF_non_topmed_sas=0.00000;nhomalt_non_topmed_sas=0;AC_non_cancer_eas_XX=0;AN_non_cancer_eas_XX=746;AF_non_cancer_eas_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_cancer_eas_XX=0;AC_amr_XY=0;AN_amr_XY=3650;AF_amr_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_amr_XY=0;AC_non_v2_nfe_XX=0;AN_non_v2_nfe_XX=12970;AF_non_v2_nfe_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_v2_nfe_XX=0;AC_controls_and_biobanks_XY=0;AN_controls_and_biobanks_XY=6960;AF_controls_and_biobanks_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_XY=0;AC_non_neuro_asj_XY=0;AN_non_neuro_asj_XY=722;AF_non_neuro_asj_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_non_neuro_asj_XY=0;AC_oth=0;AN_oth=782;AF_oth=0.00000;nhomalt_oth=0;AC_non_topmed_mid_XY=0;AN_non_topmed_mid_XY=82;AF_non_topmed_mid_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_non_topmed_mid_XY=0;AC_non_cancer_asj_XX=0;AN_non_cancer_asj_XX=770;AF_non_cancer_asj_XX=0.00000;nhomalt_non_cancer_asj_XX=0;AC_sas_XY=0;AN_sas_XY=860;AF_sas_XY=0.00000;nhomalt_sas_XY=0;AC_non_neuro_fin=0...
```

So there is your data.

Now the issues:

- because file is **TSV**, it is basically just more general from of **CSV** format and unfortunately this means, it is line oriented format, **not** column oriented, and that means:

  - incoming data unit is line
  - line incoming is split into columns and not vice versa
  - i.e. to get "just" first 5 columns you still need to visit all the lines in the file
  - because lines have unexpected/unpredictable lengths, structure of the data is irregular so you cannot compute required byte ranges in any meaningful way
- because file is `bgzip` compressed, it is impossible to use byte ranges anyway

  - due to errors in size calculation when using in on the fly gzip compressions in HTTP servers, byte ranges on such files are often broken
  - we don't know whether file is pre-compressed (and put into download dir) or not (and is on the fly compressed by the httpd/nginx)
  - given the size file, it is probably pre-compressed, so theoretically byte ranges could work, but you would still need index to map respective uncompressed lines into respective BGZIP block which is probably task above your level (given you are asking this question - it would not be profitable even on my level given time effort ratio (I would need weeks/months))
  - even if you got the indexing working you still need to download/parse the whole file and even then the moment file is changed upstream the index breaks
- easiest for you is to hope that google download servers are setup in such a way that they won't kill your connection even if it lingers for hours/days.

Given last point you could do what @user10489 is saying:

1. start streaming file from google servers with `curl` and pipe it to `zcat`
2. attach end of the `zcat` output with pipe to input of some quickly hacked together script: perl, python, php, lua
3. in the script parse each incoming line for first five columns delimited with tabs, and store those columns into separate data file locally (TSV, or I would suggest `sqlite3`) - you also have to ignore comments at the beginning of dataset mentioned above.

The final usage would look something like this:

```
: curl -s -L https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data--gnomad/release/3.1.2/vcf/genomes/gnomad.genomes.v3.1.2.sites.chr1.vcf.bgz | zcat | myscript my-outfile.tsv
```

You get the picture.

This is doable in couple in minutes/hours, depending on your ability, but now you will have following problems:

- you need to setup your pipeline in a way so it can run unattended for hours (tmux, screen)
- even if you implement line counting and store the last processed line in a sentinel file, if ever you script crashes in the middle of the processing, you will need to restart the download from beginning, and either wait until you reach the stored line, or, in this case, it is simply easier to reprocess everything again on restart
- you don't know that "only first 5 columns" extracted will be substantially smaller than 128GB compressed - you might run out of space during processing anyway
- finally we don't know whether google servers don't have some "download  connection taking too long" protection, so they might sever their link to `curl` head of pipeline prematurely - and that means it will be effectively for you still **impossible** to stream the whole file down.

So in your case I would go to project/research lead or management and request resources: drive, perhaps vm/node, download whole file as intended and preprocess it locally. Analyze resulting pre-processed 5 column file length/size, and upload to servers only that.

You won't depend on google server not severing your pipeline, and you can rerun and tune your pipeline as many times as you want. You won't have to worry about "will 5 columns "only" fit into storage?" question either.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Almost all your command lines start with a colon. This is a no-op. Was that just for testing, and got accidentally left in?

Comment: Sorry, corrected my confusing wording on "binaries" and "TSVs".

Comment: @roaima - I am sorry, I use this so long I forgot - this my shell prompt setup, I use : instead of $. It works better in my own tooling (cli capture markup) and also protects others from "dumb" copy pasting. Do you think I should edit them to something more normal?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't show the prompt at all - it's then far easier for people to copy and paste the code

Comment: If you know the size of compressed bz file, then adding `pv -s 182G` after `curl` will give a download progress. If you know the headers don't have TABs then adding `-s` to `cut` will make it filer out lines without enough TABs (instead of using `tail`). To compress the output, use, at the end, `xz -9 -T 7` where `7` is one less than the number of cores. You can add `-e` to `xz` to get another 3% of compression, but this will use around 84MB of RAM _per core_, and makes it run very bursty. You might want to unbuffer the input to xz if you do this

Comment: Unbuffering is done by using `stdbuf -i1G xz…` but this adds another 1G of RAM usage

Comment: In the case of this kind of file, the headers are actually essential. The file isn't a valid VCF file without them. So although a very reasonable assumption, in this case you really don't want to remove any of the headers.

Comment: Oh, also, bgzip _is_ indexed and the index file will almost certainly be downloadable from the same source (on mobile now, can't check). You said that could help at your level, it might be worth checking out.

Comment: @CSM you don't need to add `pv` to see download progress. Just remove the "silent operation" flag (`-s`) from `curl` and it will do that itself

Comment: @roaima if you wouldn't include to prompt start how would users know it's a prompt?

Comment: @CSM - I was using tail as an example. As I said at his point I would write my own line selector in php/lua/python or something, although using `cut` as in @roaima's answer is certainly a smart trick and does a quick job of the column splitting

Comment: @terdon the asker never specified whether first 5-column selection needs to be valid VCF (whatever that is) or not. Even more reason to write your own quick line selector script - or mess around with `awk`,`cut`, perhaps even `sed`.

Comment: I also want to remind everybody question was about downloading and not filter processing, so all the edits others made wtr to column splitting and other things are kinda "extra" info to the answer.

Comment: @terdon so you are saying there is way to get index of bgz compressed blocks somehow, without the need to scan the whole file first? Because it could be interesting tool perhaps. I have no idea how the bgzf format is organized - at first I thought there is block index at the beginnig of the stream - so I though theoretically you could somehow, map blocks to lines - but more and more I think about it this, it is not doable without streaming through whole 128GBs of the file first, to create block line map, making 2 pass op, which defeats purpose of creating such map in first place...

Comment: @etosan I am saying there _might_ be a way and I would be curious to find out. I really doubt it, since the indexing could be used to give me specific lines, maybe, but I don't see how it could give specific fields of all lines. I only mentioned it since your answer suggested you're an expert in this sort of thing so I thought you might have been intrigued (see https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html).

Comment: @etosan, "_question was about downloading and not filter processing_" - the OP said they only wanted the first five tab-separated columns. That means column splitting most definitely is on topic for an answer

Answer (score 7):

- If the file wasn't compressed, it is possible in the http protocol to download ranges of bytes.  However, this probably isn't useful without an index, even if it is possible.
- If the file is compressed with stream compression, you have to download the whole thing to decompress any of it.  A lot of stream compressors actually do sequential compressed blocks, but again, without an index of those blocks, it's basically not feasible, and if you're trying to get single column rather than a range of large chunks, it's not possible.
- If it's not the network bandwidth but the disk space you are having problems with, there's lots of options.  Download the thing to memory, stream uncompress it in memory, send the uncompressed data to a process that extracts the column you need and write it out.  This can all be done in a single pipeline with `wget -O - | bgzcat |` ... and stream based tools that can take input on stdin and write what you need to stdout or a file.

Comment: Downloading a range of bytes is useful if you have fixed-width fields, but the whole point of a delimited format like TSV is to allow variable-width fields. (Maybe that's what you're alluding to with the mention of an index, which might provide the location of the delimiters in each line.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning *HTTP range requests* even though it won't directly answer this specific question. It may help answer *related* questions, though. I believe the problem as stated is actually impossible to solve without downloading the whole file (even if you aren't obligated to *store* the whole file).

Comment: Downloading a range of bytes, even without fixed width fields, would still be useful...but only if you had an index of where the records started.  But without that, or with compression, as I said, not really an option.

Comment: @user10489 - yes but you still need to dl. the whole file which means at least two passes that is the the point Christopher Schultz is making I believe. This would inflate you download speed at least 1 time (128GB time) to build the index. However should you build the index this would allow to share it among multiple machines.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, it is technically impossible to download only certain columns of a file using wget.

You would need to filter the data before you download it, which means the data should be filtered server-side.  A simple compressed file on an HTTPS server does not provide this capability.

Other alternatives:

- It might be worth investigating if you can access the data in different ways.  Perhaps the Tab Separated Value (TSV) file is actually the output of a database dump, and you can query the database directly using an Application Programming Interface (API).  Perhaps there exists a way to tailor the data based on a Representational state transfer (REST) API or otherwise.  You may wish to confirm with the data provider if such an interface is publicly available.  It would seem unexpected that such a huge TSV file is the way in which they store the data internally.
- You may be able to bring your code to the data rather than the data to the code.  Apparently, the data are stored in multiple clouds.  If you have a tenancy in either of them, you can access the data much more quickly, perhaps filtering it down to be small enough for you to store before downloading it to your local system.